# What is query_cache_min_res_unit in mysql mariadb?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, mariadb

What is **query_cache_min_res_unit** option in mysql when setting query caching. Also i have seen a word **block** when reading about **query_cache_min_res_unit** on the internet but i didn't understand what that **block** word mean.

Can any one tell me in **simple and easy** words what these two means and where and why these two are used ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/query-cache/

It says:

> There are two main ways to limit the size of the query cache. First,
>   the overall size in bytes is determined by the query_cache_size server
>   variable. About 40KB is needed for various query cache structures.
>
> The query cache size is allocated in 1024 byte-blocks, thus it should
>   be set to a multiple of 1024.
>
> **The query result is stored using a minimum block size of
>   query_cache_min_res_unit.** Check two conditions to use a good value of
>   this variable: Query cache insert result blocks with locks, each new
>   block insert lock query cache, a small value will increase locks and
>   fragmentation and waste less memory for small results, a big value
>   will increase memory use wasting more memory for small results but it
>   reduce locks. Test with your workload for fine tune this variable.

Comment: Please don't share any link i have already inspected all the internet as i already mentioned in question. If you know about the question then please answer in your own easy words, otherwise please don't copy and past any thing from any site.

Answer (score 0):

Rather that answer the question, I will suggest that the answer is moot...

Don't use the Query Cache for serious production sites.  *Any* writes to a table cause the purging of *all* entries in the QC for that table.  For that reason, a site with a lot of writes have very little use for the QC.

And, I will make a stab at the real question...  Since there are no good metrics (in `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`) for judging whether `query_cache_min_res_unit` is too big or too small, it is best to leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

BLOCK refers to the number of bytes in this case.

query_cache_min_res_unit is the MINIMUM number of bytes to be RESERVED for EVERY result stored in Query Cache results.

After 4 years of practical production use, 512 works well for the application I have supported.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an easy explanation to this, and eventually came up with:

the default value `1024 bytes` says for example if a query size is `10 bytes` it will take `1024 bytes` of your `query_cache_size` and it's a waste because you could save it in for example a `64 byes` block.

but if you make `64 bytes` blocks for this and a query size is `2000 bytes` then you would create 31 blocks of `64 bytes` to store the `2000 bytes` query in the cache and it will increase fragmentation...

so you have to experiment with the number in order to find the best value for your application.

according to documentation [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/query-cache/#examining-the-query-cache) will help you fine tune this settings:

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';
+-------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name           | Value    |
+-------------------------+----------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 1158     |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 3760784  |
| Qcache_hits             | 31943398 |
| Qcache_inserts          | 42998029 |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 34695322 |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 652482   |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 4628     |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 11123    |
+-------------------------+----------+
```